# custom routes with 2 parameters, id and customerid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

for example you have custom route like this:

`CustomerOrder/{action}/{id}/customerid={customerid}`

the url became like this:

`CustomerOrder/Create/customerid=1`

how can you get the customerid and use it in the view?

`<%= Html.MenuItem("Back to List", "Index", new { customerID = ???????? })%>`

Comment: Can't you change your request URLs to match this route: CostomerOrder/{action}/{id}/{customerId} ?

Comment: is there any difference?

Comment: what's the question then?... sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heres the code in Global.ASAX

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute("CustomerOrders", "CustomerOrder/{action}/{id}/customerid={customerid}",
                       new { customerid= "{customerid}", controller = "CustomerOrder", action = "Index", id = "" });

        routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" });           

    }
```

Comment: CustomerOrders isn't a correct url, as you're not specifying a ? in any case.

Comment: Surely, at the least, you should have to do: CustomerOrder/{action}/{id}/?customerid={customerid}

Comment: Please update your question with this, rather than add it as a new answer.

Comment: i got it..
the url must be CustomerOrder/{action}/{customerid}/{id}
because customerid always have a value.

now going back to my question. 
since the url is CustomerOrder/Index/1
and 1 is the customerid (not orderid),

if i have an actionlink like this in my Index View,
Html.ActionLink("Create New Order", "Create", new {projectid = ?????})

how can i get the value of the projectid(?????) so i can pass it to the create action?

Answer (score 3):

The equals sign is going to confuse url parsers since it has special meaning.

If you were to change your route to:

```
routes.MapRoute("CustomerOrder", "CustomerOrder/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Order", id = "" });
```

Then the following view code

```
<%= Html.MenuItem("Back to List", "Index", new { customerID = 5 })%>
```

Would create a link to:

```
CustomerOrder/Index/?customerid=5
```

which would work just fine.

**Note**

Given your current routing configuration, you would get the exact same results by deleting your CustomerOrder route since it is broken and you get the desired results from the default route.

Comment: I tried to change it to <code> ?customerid = 1 </code> but this error occured..

The route URL cannot start with a '/' or '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.
Parameter name: routeUrl

Comment: @fleents: Can you copy your route configuration in Global.asax.cs? It would probably help. And put it in your original question. Not here...

Comment: @Fleents: you can't put querystrings in the route. Phil Haack discusses that they're not used here: http://haacked.com/archive/2007/12/17/testing-routes-in-asp.net-mvc.aspx#58629

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to MVC but I'm thinking the controller gets a customerid parameter and that could be passed to the View (via ViewData), no?